# How To: View variable passed to a compiled .net method

Tags: c#, .net, ssms, overriding

Alright, so here is the story..

My organization has a database that we sell to the clients. We sometimes have to make client specific modifications.

I am developing an extension to Sql Server Management Studio(SSMS) 2008 R2 SP1.

This extension will generate DDL and gather schema information to pass to a web service hosted locally. To Generate the DDL I am scripting database objects inside of SSMS via SMO.
([Example](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scripting-database-objects-using-smo-updated))

SSMS 2008 has a handy feature to do this basically the same way I am. 
( Well why not use SSMS;  - Because it needs to be automated by my tool, thanks)

SSMS does it right; I can't figure out how to do it right. They set the appropriate Scripting Options([MS Refrence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions_properties.aspx)). When generating DDL you have to do things in a specif order.( Database ->tables ->Keys ->Views-> -> etc) MS does this order right, using the correct Scripting Options.

My attempts to override the method have failed and my research has not provided the needed information.

...

[LONG STORY SHORT]

I would like a way to overide the method "Script(ScriptingOptions scriptingOptions)" Method to view the actual Scripting Options set
-- Perhaps I may even be going about this the wrong way and guidance is welcome. I'd still like to know if I can and how though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try emission: [TypeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethodoverride.aspx)

For example: [Is there a way to "override" a method with reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684804/is-there-a-way-to-override-a-method-with-reflection)