# Overriding method in DLL using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, dll

I am not even sure if this is possible so apologies if not.  I have googled quite extensively and not found what I am looking for.

Basically we have an application produced by a third party, which, to be perfectly blunt is rubbish.  We have a particular issue and have managed to trace the problem using ILSpy to a method within a DLL.  Obviously we don't have (nor are able to get) the source code and the company in question is unwilling to fix the problem in any reasonable timescales.

So, we've investigated various avenues of investigation and come up with nothing.  I've been looking into seeing whether this can be done using reflection and this is pretty much the last hope we have of getting this to work.  In a nutshell, what I would like to do is the following:

- Create a simple class library with the same name as the existing DLL
- Use reflection to import the methods from the existing DLL
- Somehow override the method in question with my own, correct code
- Rebuild the code, so I have a new DLL, containing 99% of the functionality of the existing DLL but with my override code providing the correct functionality.

I have found, during my investigations TypeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride and also a page from StackOverflow, which seems similar but not quite what I am looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethodoverride.aspx

[Is there a way to "override" a method with reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684804/is-there-a-way-to-override-a-method-with-reflection)

Any advice appreciated!

Andrew

## Edit

The other possible idea I has was to produce a partial class containing the override function, but that didn't seem feasible either.

Comment: Wondering if an interceptor based approach would work here - something like Castle DynamicProxy: http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/ - obviously you wouldn't be completely replacing the method call, but you could certainly intercept/error handle and tweak (oh yeah and it depends if the class has virtual methods)

Comment: Why not just make a class, as you said, that calls the third party class for most of the things except the method you want to override? Or derive from that class and use another name for that method? Also do you really need that to be inside 1 unique dll? Why not split it in 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the method only if it is virtual, and it doesn't matter whether you do it through reflection or statically. I would suggest using a decompiler (there are a lot of free ones available) and fixing the code in MSIL. Then you can generate a new assembly from the MSIL.

Comment: Yeah, I've just checked and the method isn't virtual, so thats one idea out the window.  I'm just checking decompilers now - thanks for your advice.

Comment: how about the sign and publickeytoken? does it remain the same ?!

Comment: If the DLL is signed (it has a strong name) then after modification you need to resign it with the strong name's certificate.

Comment: hi, i am using [this](https://github.com/typesafe/mnailgun/blob/635e11208b8fe1f88bd767c806bfce0ad8691ee8/src/Typesafe.Mailgun/MailgunClient.cs) small .net wrapper to send mail using mail gun `api`, as you can see in the code they have compiled it `https://api.mailgun.net/v2/` version 2 of api i want to change it to version 3 `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/`, what can be done ?

Comment: If the code is open source, then you can just download it, change the URL and recompile the DLL. If you don't have access to the source code, then you can try to decompile the assembly, change the URL and compile it to a new DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first idea is good.
If the third party class isn't `sealed`, you can derive from it, and add your own method, with a different name, to correct the behavior that is wrong.
If you need it to be in 1 dll, you can use [IlMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630).

If your third party class is sealed you can just have an instance of this third party class in your new class and call the methods when needed.

But you'll have to check that the method you want to "override" isn't called inside that library, because if it is this solution won't work...

It's not very clean, but it can be a temporary solution during the time the company that edits the library fixes the problem.

And when it's fixed you'd just have to rename the method you use, so it won't be time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described I would recommend modifying the original assembly.  The process is essentially

- Decompile the assembly into MSIL, C# or whatever language you so choose
- Modify the decompiled assembly to include your changes
- Recompile the assembly using the modified source

From what I can see [Reflexil](http://reflexil.net/) allows you to do just that, although it may require that you buy Resharper (I've not tried it myself)

Alternatively you can use [ILDasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to decompile the entire assembly to a single file, modify the file and then recompile it using [ILAsm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm coming in a bit late on this, but I'd agree with Charleh; if you've got a class that's not behaving well and isn't conducive to substitution, but at least declares its methods as `virtual`, then you're in luck. The following uses references to `Castle.Core` and `Patterns`:

```
var interceptor = new DelegateInterceptor(proceed: call => 
{
  if(ShouldCallProceed(call)) call.Proceed();
  else AlternativeLogic();
});

var generator = new ProxyGenerator();
var proxy = generator.CreateClassProxy<UncooperativeType>(interceptor);

proxy.RubbishMethod();
```

I've also taken the liberty of providing [a running sample of this](http://share.linqpad.net/s6xq7t.linq) in LinqPad. It shows the difference between methods that allow interception (`virtual` ones) and ones that don't. It also shows a useful way of trapping exceptions without all the code using `Try.Do` from `Patterns`.