# Get an event hook to Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, windows, console, console.writeline, tracelistener

In a c# console application, is there a way to get a notification whenever text is written to the console via `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.Write`?

Whenever this event fires, it should be possible to do things like change the text before it is written, redirect it to a file, or change the current Console.ForegroundColor.

I know that a simple way to accomplish this is to never call `Console.WriteLine` directly, but instead always call my own custom wrapper method.

Another even better approach is to write a custom `ConsoleTraceListener`, and output all text via `trace.TraceInformation()`.
I have done that and it works just fine.

However this does not work if the Console.WriteLine call is inside another assembly which should remain unchanged.

So is there any way to react to `Console.WriteLine` calls without modifying the code that makes those calls?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting the Console standard output to your own stream?

Comment: Try monkey patching Console.WriteLine, eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684804/is-there-a-way-to-override-a-method-with-reflection I've never tried this myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Console.SetOut to set a custom Writer class. In this class you can make your own write function.