# How to Override a single function of a system class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to override the `ToString()` function of the `GroupPrincipal` class within `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` without having to create a child class. I feel like i have done something very similar before but can't seem to remember how.

I tried this as a test but it seems to override the entire class

```
public class GroupPrincipal
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: and what problems are you having with your current implementation?

Comment: as stated it overrides the entire class basically creating a class with only a ToString function

Comment: The main question is: Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: So do you not have access to the source of `GroupPrincipal`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to "override" a method with reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684804/is-there-a-way-to-override-a-method-with-reflection)

Comment: Markus Safar the reason is i was using a arraylist of GroupPrincipals as the datasource for a listbox and it automatically calls the ToString function to return just the name and i wanted more information. I realize there are many other ways to do this just thought I might could just override the ToString function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to change methods of an existing class without inheriting it. That is not possible (at least not without reflection).

Creating a subclass is the proper way to do this.

Comment: Alrighty ill just make a sub class just thought there might be a way, maybe that was c++ ...been a long time.

Answer (score -2):

Here you have not specified the base for your class.  Therefore, it only derives from the default, `object`.

Try:

```
public class GroupPrincipal : AccountManagement
{
    // Method overrides here...
}
```

Of course, in a sense this does "override the entire class."  But because of the wonders of OOP, the child class inherits its behaviour from the base until you start overriding members yourself.  There is little overhead to doing this.

If the `AccountManagement` class has non-default constructors, you might need to add corresponding constructors to your class too.  These would probably pass through to their counterparts in the base type.  For example, you might have:

```
public GroupPrincipal(string name)
    : base(name)
{
}
```

Comment: He stated clearly, that he does NOT want to create a child class.

Comment: Problem is AccountManagement is a namespace not a class. other wise its kind of what i tried before.

Comment: OK.  You cannot "override" a member of a type inside the same type.  (The term itself implies that you have a derived type.)  You could be confusing the concept of "overloading" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029(v=vs.110).aspx, but probably not what you're after), or maybe partial methods (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).