# How to hide the Items property in custom ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I am creating a custom control that inherits from ComboBox. I need to perform a custom action when a Item is added to the ComboBox. It doesn't matter if it's C# or Vb.NET, but I don't know how to do it.

Looks like it's not worth the effort to modify everything to detect it, as seen here:
[Event to detect item added to ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24761600/1967056)

So maybe is possible to create my custom `.Add();` method, but then I need to hide the `Items` property so the control doesn't allow two different method of adding and only one working.

I tried using things in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/73774ee1-fdb6-45da-a4e1-dff044ba8eb2/overriding-combobox-items-property) but I didn't manage to make it work. For example, I tried putting the overloaded property `private`, but didn't change anything, as seen in this example in Vb.NET:

```vb
Private Overloads ReadOnly Property Items() As ObjectCollection
'...
```

Can it be done?

Comment: how would they add things if you shadow out `Items`?

Comment: @Plutonix With my custom `AddItem` method

Comment: ok, how would I do `For each s as string in yourCBO.Items`; or get `Items.Count` or do `Items.Contains` or .remove or .removeat?  See the problem?

Comment: @Plutonix So I'll need to expose some custom methods, but it's not unreasonable, isn't it?

Comment: Hiding is easy: `public List<object> Items { get; set; }` or whatever type you seem fit. But how will you get things into the real, hidden Items collection, which will be used on the UI??

Comment: @TaW As I said to Plutonix, with custom methods (`addItem()`, `count()`, etc)

Comment: Since `Items` is public the user will always be able to do `Items.Add` and you cant stop them.  Since `items` is not marked as Overridable you cant replace it with your own rendition.  might be of interest: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListBox@cs/1305376/ListBox@cs

Comment: There is an interesting new answer by Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå to the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761600/event-to-detect-item-added-to-combobox#24761829). This would clearly be much better than the hack of hiding the Items..!

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Yes you can **hide** the original Items collection and replace it by **something** else.

However your new 'custom' Items won't be able to **work**; it is always null - at least that's what I found. Maybe somebody can jump in with details of the why..?

Which is why I replace it with something rather useless - a naked object.

What you **can** do is this: You can expose the original Items in a man-in-the-middle class and use it in your custom ComboBox class. You could e.g. name the exposed class Items_ and create a class to replace the Items in the final inheritance level. This class needs to implement all methods and properties you want your custom class's consumers to have.

I have named to custom Items 'items'  and implemented one method and one property.
(For non-case sensitive VB maybe Itemz would be better ;-)

Here is the minimal man-in-the-middle :

```
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class mimComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public ObjectCollection items_;

    public mimComboBox()
    {
        items_ = Items;
    }

}
```

And here is a custom ComboBox:

```
public class myComboBox : mimComboBox
{
    public myComboBox()
    {
        Items = new object();               // (1)
        items = new myItems(this);
    }

    new public object Items { get; set; }  // this hides the real Items  (2)
    public myItems items { get; set; }     // this is the custom property

    public class myItems // the custom Items class with all necessary methods etc..
    {
        public myItems( myComboBox parent )
        {
            parentCB = parent;  // reference to the outer class
        }

        private mimComboBox parentCB;  // the man-in-the-middle

        // all your methods..
        new public int Add(object o)  // one example of a custom method
        {
            // add your item-added event here
            return parentCB.items_.Add(o);
        }

        // one of many many properties  to provide..
        public int Count { get { return parentCB.items_.Count; } } 

    }

}
```

This is an example how the ComboBox can be used:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myComboBox1.items.Add("uiuiuiiui");
    // myComboBox1.Items.Add("sadsds");  // <== this doesn't compile! (3)
    button1.Text = myComboBox1.items.Count.ToString();
}
```

This sounds like quite some work!!

(Maybe the man-in-the-middle class is not necessary..? I'd like to learn about that..!)

Edit: I have changed a few details according to the link in Plutonix' comment.

Notes:

- As noted, the original question is better solved by listening to the ComboBox system  messages
- I still wonder why this happens:

When I replace (1) & (2) by

```
Items = new myItems(this);
new public myItems Items { get; set; }
```

then (3) will compile just fine. However upon runtime it throws a null object reference error.

Is this a belated effect of the missing Overridable attribute? @Jon Skeet to the rescue! ;-)

Comment: **very** interesting. In part this only works in C#; converted to VB (I think more clearly in VB) Intellisence is showing and using `.items_` - this is because VB is not case sensitive so `items` cannot replace `Items`.  I made a few tweaks trying to get it more functional; feel free to add/change/ignore as desired: http://pastebin.com/fSF6ZjTf

Answer (score 1):

**MyComboBox** acts as normal combobox (by overwriting Item property) with extended events (ItemAdded, ItemRemoved)

**Sample Usage:**

```
    MyComboBox1.Items.Add("0")
    MyComboBox1.Items.AddRange(New String() {"1", "2", "3", "55"})
    MyComboBox1.Items.Remove("55")
    MyComboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0)
    Debug.WriteLine(MyComboBox1.Items.IndexOf("2")) '2
    Debug.WriteLine(MyComboBox1.Items.IndexOf("55")) '-1
    MyComboBox1.Items.Clear()
```

**VB.NET Code:**

```
Public Class MyComboBox
Inherits ComboBox

Public Event ItemAdded As EventHandler
'Public Event ItemsAdded As EventHandler
Public Event ItemRemoved As EventHandler
'Public Event ItemInserted(sender As Object, insertedIndex As Integer, e As EventArgs)

Private ItemContainer_ As ItemContainer

Sub New()

    ItemContainer_ = New ItemContainer(Me)

    AddHandler ItemContainer_.ItemAdded, AddressOf ItemContainer_ItemAdded
    'AddHandler ItemContainer_.ItemsAdded, AddressOf ItemContainer_ItemsAdded
    AddHandler ItemContainer_.ItemRemoved, AddressOf ItemContainer_ItemRemoved
    'AddHandler ItemContainer_.ItemInserted, AddressOf ItemContainer_ItemInserted

End Sub

Private Sub ItemContainer_ItemAdded(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ItemAdded(Me, e)
End Sub
'Private Sub ItemContainer_ItemsAdded(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
'    RaiseEvent ItemsAdded(Me, e)
'End Sub
Private Sub ItemContainer_ItemRemoved(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ItemRemoved(Me, e)
End Sub
'Private Sub ItemContainer_ItemInserted(sender As Object, insertedIndex As Integer, e As EventArgs)
'    RaiseEvent ItemInserted(Me, insertedIndex, e)
'End Sub

Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Items As ItemContainer
    Get
        Return ItemContainer_
    End Get
End Property
Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Items(index As Integer) As Object
    Get
        Return ItemContainer_.Item(index)
    End Get
End Property


Public Class ItemContainer
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection

    Public Event ItemAdded As EventHandler
    'Public Event ItemsAdded As EventHandler
    Public Event ItemRemoved As EventHandler
    'Public Event ItemInserted(sender As Object, insertedIndex As Integer, e As EventArgs)


    Private owner_ As ComboBox

    Sub New(owner As ComboBox)
        MyBase.New(owner)
        owner_ = owner
    End Sub


    Public Overloads Sub Add(item As Object)
        owner_.Items.Add(item)
        RaiseEvent ItemAdded(Me, New EventArgs)
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub AddRange(item() As Object)
        owner_.Items.AddRange(item)
        'RaiseEvent ItemsAdded(Me, New EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent ItemAdded(Me, New EventArgs)
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub Insert(index As Integer, item As Object)
        owner_.Items.Insert(index, item)
        'RaiseEvent ItemInserted(Me, index, New EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent ItemAdded(Me, New EventArgs)
    End Sub



    Public Overloads Sub Remove(item As Object)
        owner_.Items.Remove(item)
        RaiseEvent ItemRemoved(Me, New EventArgs)
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub RemoveAt(index As Integer)
        owner_.Items.RemoveAt(index)
        RaiseEvent ItemRemoved(Me, New EventArgs)
    End Sub
    Public Overloads Sub Clear()
        owner_.Items.Clear()
        RaiseEvent ItemRemoved(Me, New EventArgs)
    End Sub



    Public Overloads Function IndexOf(value As Object) As Integer
        Return owner_.Items.IndexOf(value)
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function Contains(value As Object) As Boolean
        Return owner_.Items.Contains(value)
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return owner_.Items.GetHashCode
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function ToString() As String
        Return owner_.Items.ToString
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.IEnumerator
        Return owner_.Items.GetEnumerator
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        Return owner_.Items.Equals(obj)
    End Function
    Public Overloads Function Equals(objA As Object, objB As Object) As Boolean
        Return Object.Equals(objA, objB)
    End Function

    Public Overloads Sub CopyTo(Destination() As Object, arrayIndex As Integer)
        owner_.Items.CopyTo(Destination, arrayIndex)
    End Sub



    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Count As Integer
        Get
            Return owner_.Items.Count
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly As Boolean
        Get
            Return owner_.Items.IsReadOnly
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Item(index As Integer) As Object
        Get
            Return owner_.Items.Item(index)
        End Get
    End Property


End Class
```

End Class

**C# Code:**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class MyComboBox : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
{

    public event EventHandler ItemAdded;
    //public event EventHandler ItemsAdded;
    public event EventHandler ItemRemoved;
    public event ItemInsertedEventHandler ItemInserted;
    public delegate void ItemInsertedEventHandler(object sender, int insertedIndex, EventArgs e);


    private ItemContainer ItemContainer_;

    public MyComboBox()
    {
        ItemContainer_ = new ItemContainer(this);

        ItemContainer_.ItemAdded += ItemContainer_ItemAdded;
        //ItemContainer_.ItemsAdded += ItemContainer_ItemsAdded;
        ItemContainer_.ItemRemoved += ItemContainer_ItemRemoved;
        ItemContainer_.ItemInserted += ItemContainer_ItemInserted;

    }

    private void ItemContainer_ItemAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemAdded != null)
        {
            ItemAdded(this, e);
        }
    }
    /*private void ItemContainer_ItemsAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemsAdded != null)
        {
            ItemsAdded(this, e);
        }
    }*/
    private void ItemContainer_ItemRemoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemRemoved != null)
        {
            ItemRemoved(this, e);
        }
    }
    private void ItemContainer_ItemInserted(object sender, int insertedIndex, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemInserted != null)
        {
            ItemInserted(this, insertedIndex, e);
        }
    }

    public new ItemContainer Items
    {
        get { return ItemContainer_; }
    }


    public class ItemContainer : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection
    {

        public event EventHandler ItemAdded;
        //public event EventHandler ItemsAdded;
        public event EventHandler ItemRemoved;
        public event ItemInsertedEventHandler ItemInserted;
        public delegate void ItemInsertedEventHandler(object sender, int insertedIndex, EventArgs e);



        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox owner_;
        public ItemContainer(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox owner)
            : base(owner)
        {
            owner_ = owner;
        }


        public new void Add(object item)
        {
            owner_.Items.Add(item);
            if (ItemAdded != null)
            {
                ItemAdded(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }

        public new void AddRange(object[] item)
        {
            owner_.Items.AddRange(item);
            /*if (ItemsAdded != null)
            {
                ItemsAdded(this, new EventArgs());
            }*/

            if (ItemAdded != null)
            {
                ItemAdded(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }

        public new void Insert(int index, object item)
        {
            owner_.Items.Insert(index, item);
            if (ItemInserted != null)
            {
                ItemInserted(this, index, new EventArgs());
            }
        }



        public new void Remove(object item)
        {
            owner_.Items.Remove(item);
            if (ItemRemoved != null)
            {
                ItemRemoved(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }

        public new void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            owner_.Items.RemoveAt(index);
            if (ItemRemoved != null)
            {
                ItemRemoved(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
        public new void Clear()
        {
            owner_.Items.Clear();
            if (ItemRemoved != null)
            {
                ItemRemoved(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }



        public new int IndexOf(object value)
        {
            return owner_.Items.IndexOf(value);
        }

        public new bool Contains(object value)
        {
            return owner_.Items.Contains(value);
        }

        public new int GetHashCode()
        {
            return owner_.Items.GetHashCode();
        }

        public new string ToString()
        {
            return owner_.Items.ToString();
        }

        public new System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return owner_.Items.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public new bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return owner_.Items.Equals(obj);
        }
        public new bool Equals(object objA, object objB)
        {
            return object.Equals(objA, objB);
        }

        public new void CopyTo(object[] Destination, int arrayIndex)
        {
            owner_.Items.CopyTo(Destination, arrayIndex);
        }


        public new int Count
        {
            get { return owner_.Items.Count; }
        }

        public new object this[int index]
        {
            get { return owner_.Items[index]; }
        }

        public new bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return owner_.Items.IsReadOnly; }
        }

    }

}
```