# How to Override a C# method in existing DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, overriding

I have an instance where I am using someone else's library, imported as a DLL. I just want to change only two private functions in that class. I really like to do this externally to the DLL, so when that other person releases a new DLL, I can just quickly update my DLL, and not have to alter the source and build my own DLL.

Is it possible to do this? Can I somehow override a few private functions in C# dll externally from the DLL?

Comment: Can you derive from their class?

Comment: I presume I could, yes. But the functions I want to change are private.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this was possible.

Comment: If they're *private*, then no. Your best best might be creating a wrapper around that class, i.e., use *composition* instead of *inheritance*.

Comment: Your best option is to coordinate with the author of the DLL, to expose those methods as protected and virtual so that you can override them. There's no built-in mechanism to accomplish this.

Comment: Well... with the magic of dynamic proxy, interception, and a bit of reflection, you most certainly *can* accomplish this.

Comment: There is a way to use reflection to pull out and instantiate private methods, testers do this often.  I agree that attempting to do this is just not that good of a thing.... but it can be done.

Comment: Do you intend for this to be maintainable? Then you'd better document the solution very carefully if you expect others to understand it two years from now.

Answer (score 1):

> I really like to do this externally to the DLL, so when that other
>   person releases a new DLL, I can just quickly update my DLL

Think about this. Let's say you successfully intercept/override their private functions. What will happen when the next release removes those functions or changes their behavior?

Members are usually private for a reason.

Valid approaches are to wrap the external assembly to control/abstract behavior, or to override public/protected members that are designed for inheritance.

Calling private members is easy with reflection. *Modifying* them so that their callers use a new implementation is more complex.

> and not have to alter the source and build my own DLL.

If you really, really need to do this, altering the source is probably the most straightforward approach.* You could also look at [IL weaving](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671259/Reweaving-IL-code-with-Mono-Cecil) which might be appropriate for this task.

A better approach would be to work with the author to make the library more extensible in the areas that you require.

<sub>* This assumes you have legitimate access to the source or are allowed to decompile the assembly. This could violate a reverse engineering clause in a license, invalidate a maintenance contract, etc. I am not a lawyer.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use TypeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride. See this question for details [Is there a way to "override" a method with reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684804/is-there-a-way-to-override-a-method-with-reflection).

If this doesn't work, you can try to build a runtime proxy class also using reflection but replacing calls to methods you want to override with your implementations. That's of course is a little bit of voodoo. Code instrumentation does similar things -- injecting custom code into your methods. In fact that's what I suggest researching -- how instrumentation works.