# Prevent WinForms MessageBox.Show modal popups

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

Is there a way to intercept a `MessageBox.Show(...)` call and instead return a result?

A solution is to define an abstraction like

```
interface IShowMessage {
    MessageBoxResult Show(...);
}
```

with an implementation like

```
class DoShowMessage : IShowMessage {
    MessageBoxResult Show(...) { return MessageBox.Show(...); }
}

class NeverShowMessage : IShowMessage {
    MessageBoxResult Show(...) { return MessageBoxResult.OK; }
}
```

and use either implementation when needed. However, in a current codebase this is not feasible due to the sheer amount of `MessageBox.Show(...)` calls. Still, I need to get rid of the MessageBox modal popups.

Is there any other way?

Comment: If you just want to get rid of modal `MessageBox`, you can use your own implementation and use a Find/Replace to replace all message boxes.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Reflection` to override the `MessageBox.Show` methods.

Check out this post for an example:

[Is there a way to "override" a method with reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684804/is-there-a-way-to-override-a-method-with-reflection)